# How to print entire ScrollViewer to a PDF file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, pdfsharp

I have a function that prints my layout to a PDF file (using `PDFSharp` library).

My problem is that my `Grid` includes a `ScrollViewer`.

The Problem is that the `ScrollViewer` obviously is not scrollable in the PDF file.

Is there a way i can change that ?

```cs
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "NHF Tool";
dlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf";
dlg.Filter = "PDF (.pdf)|*.pdf";

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

try
{
    if (result == true)
    {
        MemoryStream lMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        Package package = Package.Open(lMemoryStream, FileMode.Create);
        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(package);
        XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
        writer.Write(MainCanvas);
        doc.Close();
        package.Close();
        var pdfXpsDoc = PdfSharp.Xps.XpsModel.XpsDocument.Open(lMemoryStream);
        PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(pdfXpsDoc, dlg.FileName, 0);
    }
}
catch (System.IO.IOException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("TEMP");
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="NHF_Tool.MainWindow" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:my="clr-namespace:NHF_Tool"
  Title="Test" Height="800" Width="1525">

    <Grid Background="Gainsboro">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Test1" Margin="10">
            <Grid>
                <Button Content="Sample content" Margin="20"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="Test2" Margin="10">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Rectangle Fill="LightYellow" Height="300" Margin="20"/>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Text="TextBox"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Maybe you could temporarily change the `MainWindow.Height` property to something large enough, wait for a new layout/render pass and only then print to PDF?

Comment: That seems like a good idea.

Comment: Can you make your sample XAML fully functional? Remove any useless markup, add closing tags, populate it with sample data etc. We want to be able to copy paste your code and immediately understand your issue.

Comment: I edited one TextBox. It naturally gets cut off.

Comment: It looks like you have *a lot* of hardcoded values for `Margin`, `Width`, `Height`... throughout your XAML, which makes your window absolutely not responsive. I legit think that the first step for you is to remove than main `Canvas` and start using a more appropriate layout panel like a `Grid`. Resizing will be much easier afterwards.

Comment: I edited your XAML to make it clearer to you. It will be easier to work from this sample XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily increase your `MainWindow.Height` (or `Width`, depending on your `ScrollViewer` orientation) to accomodate the whole `ScrollViewer` content, wait for a new layout/render pass and only then print it to PDF.

```cs
MainWindow window = this;
double oldHeight = window.Height; // saving regular Height for rollback
window.Height = 5000; // large enough temporary increase

window.SynchronouslyRedraw();

PrintToPdf(); // the method you already have
window.Height = oldHeight; // undo temporary increase
```

I like to use this extension method for synchronous redrawing operations:

```cs
public static class UIElementExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Synchronously redraws this <see cref="UIElement"/>. Only works if in a <see cref="Window"/> visual tree.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SynchronouslyRedraw(this UIElement uiElement) {
        uiElement.InvalidateVisual();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() => { })).Wait();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => { })).Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually what i forgot to tell is that the ScrollViewer in in a Combobox and the Combobox is in my MainCanvas. So i tried changing the Combobox.Height and the MainCanvas.Height and than PrintToPdf but it does not work. I can see how the Height changes but in the Output only the Groupbox is expanded but cut off by the Canvas.

Comment: You should increase the canvas height too then, or temporarily set ``Canvas.ClipToBounds`` to `false`.

Comment: I did this and still it does not work. MainWindow window = this;
            window.Height = 2000;
            MainCanvas.Height = 1540;
            GroupBox.Height = 1380;

Comment: please edit your question to provide a minimal XAML sample so that I can try in your specific case!

Comment: What fixxed my problem was setting the min.height of my window to the new height otherwise it would not change it eventhough min.height was 0.